# copy an event receiver to a different server

Tags: visual-studio, event-receivers

My work is requiring me to create an event receiver for an itemAdding event for an existing list on a Sharepoint Server. My problem is that while I have access to a Sharepoint Server, I do not have access to the specific server that they want the event receiver on. So I need to copy an event receiver and it's code-behind from one sharepoint server to another.

I created a duplicate of the list on my server (same column names, types, etc.)

I have created an event receiver in Visual Studio 2010 using visual basic that takes the input of a textbox in the NewForm.aspx and adds it to a URL address (example, the hard-coded url address is http://contoso.com/claims?id= and I add the input information to it to create a URL of http://contoso.com/claims?id=1234). This URL is then displayed in a hyperlink column, which can be clicked to go to the URL. I also changed the  line in the elements.xml file in the receiver (see below.) It works great on the sharepoint server that I have access to.

Now I need to add this event receiver to the other server.

I am still learning Sharepoint so I am just not sure how a copy of a package works. I was afraid that if I used the deployed package created by VS on my server, that the Site URL in the solution properties would stick. So I changed the Site URL to the server that I don't have access to and only did a build for the solution (not a deployment since I can't deploy to the other server.)

Next I went to the VS Command Prompt, changed to the project directory, and typed "msbuild /t:Package filename.vbproj". This created a .wsp file in the bin/Debug directory of my solution. An admin for the other server copied the .wsp file to it. He added the solution and deployed it (using stsadm -o addsolution -filename filename.wsp **and** stsadm -o deploysolution -name filename.wsp), but the code-behind does not work. There weren't any error messages. The new list item is added, but the URL is not created or displayed.

What have I done wrong?

**EventReceiver1.vb**

```
Public Overrides Sub ItemAdding(properties as SPItemEventProperties)
    MyBase.ItemAdding(properties)
    Dim baseLink as String = "http://contoso.com?id="
    Dim hLink As New SPFieldUrlValue()
    hLink.Description = properties.AfterProperties("ReportID").ToString
    hLink.Url = baselink & properties.AfterProperties("ReportID").ToString
    properties.AfterProperties("URL") = hLink
End Sub
```

**Elements.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/listname">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiver1ItemAdding</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>filename.EventReceiver1</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im presuming the guy cant debug the code? so you can know that the class is being triggered? the only other thing i could think of is the assembly and class name are they the same as your .vb class?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561835/how-do-you-bound-an-event-receiver-to-a-specific-custom-content-type

hope this guides you into the right direction!

Comment: The admin for the server has no coding experience. They have made the site with basic SharePoint knowledge. I wish I had access to it so I could debug the problems! And yes, the assembly and class names are correct. I was so worried about the naming of everything that I've double and triple checked it. My main question was whether or not I've missed anything. Did I copy it all to the other server correctly? Was there a setting that I don't know about that needs to be set? Did I miss something in my code? An additional problem is that they will not put VS2010 on the SP2010 Server.